# How to get DOM live collections with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How do I get access to live DOM collections from jQuery?

Take for example this HTML `<div id='a'></div>` and this JavaScript code:

```
var a = $('#a');
var divs = a[0].getElementsByTagName('DIV');
for(var i=0; divs.length < 20; ) {
    a.append($('<div>'+(i++)+'</div>'));
}
```

It will append 20 div children to `<div id='a'>` because `divs` is a live collection.

Is there anything in jQuery that I could replace the second line with to get the same result?

`var divs = $('#a div');` results in infinite loop.

JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wDhfA/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the element each time, this will create a new jQuery object. Which I think it the only way if the element is changing.

```
var a = $('#a');

for(var i=0; $('#a div').length < 20; ) {
    a.append($('<div>'+(i++)+'</div>'));
    if(i==50) break;
}
```

EDIT:
Or this:

```
for(var i=0, a=$('#a'); a.children('div').length < 20; ) {
    a.append($('<div>'+(i++)+'</div>'));
    if(i==50) break;
}
```

Or this, just one selector:

```
var a = $('#a');
var length = a.children('div').length;

while(length < 20) {
        a.append($('<div>'+(length++)+'</div>'));
}
```

Comment: but that will execute '#a div' selector 20 times

Comment: How many times are you going to loop? It's doubtful this will affect performance.

Comment: Change to a while and count before the loop? Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

In case `#a` already contains divs:

```
var $a = $('#a'),
    toAdd = Math.max(20 - $a.find('div').length, 0);

for (var i = 0; i < toAdd; i++) {
    $a.append('<div>' + i + '</div>');
}
```

That would be equivalent to the code above.

Comment: Yes, this is the closest to what I need, if something else doesn't add another div while we're in the loop

Comment: @ʘleg: As JavaScript is single threaded, this should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Live Collections - the true ones, are not something which can be returned by modern jquery.
Moreover, modern method which is intended to replace in nearest future getElementsByTagName, getQuerySelectorAll also return a static collection.

This is the answer to question you've stated. 
As for the question you've really wanted to ask, other users already tried to provide you some help.

Comment: so are you saying that using live collections is a bad style?

Comment: well, bad is too strong word. I'd rather say that one should be very careful while relying on liveness property of the collections, since it not only less obvious, but also lesser know technique. Well, after thinking, may be "bad" is quite appropriate)))

Answer (score 1):

> How to get DOM live collections with jQuery?

That’s not possible.

This has the same effect as your example code, though:

```
var $a = $('#a');

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    $a.append('<div>' + i + '</div>');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mathias/Af538/

**Update:** If the code needs to be repeated periodically, you could use something like this:

```
var $a = $('#a'),
    toAdd = Math.max(20 - $('div', $a).length, 0),
    i;

for (i = 0; i < toAdd; i++) {
    $a.append('<div>' + i + '</div>');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mathias/S5C6n/

Comment: that loop will need to be executed periodically to make sure that there are at most 20 div children, so 20 cannot be the count for loops required

Answer (score 0):

Is it always 20 div children ?

Isn't it better to use the following

```
var a = $('#a div');
for(var i=0; i < 20; i++) {
    a.append($('<div>'+(i)+'</div>'));
}
```

Comment: 20 is just an example, and the actual number is not known at the time of coding - it will depend on the number of div children that are already there at runtime

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're looking for is:

```
var divs = $('div#a');
```

Since IDs are supposed to be unique, you could just do:

```
var divs = $('#a');
```